# Is it possible to add a externally-maintained project library, without copying?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, library-project

I'm working with Android Studio 0.5.8.

I have a Working project, and I want to reuse all its contents to make an almost identical app with only another name and different colors.

Basically I want to make a library from the original app and reuse it in various identical apps, but I don't want to copy & paste inside each new app, I want to maintain and develop only one codebase (the project library).

I have read and read, but I can'tt find any real solution.

I tried this in my `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':AppCopy1', ':..:LibraryProject'
```

It works, but I cant use any classes in `AppCopy1`.

Comment: Did you change your build file for the library project to use `apply plugin: 'android-library'` instead of `apply plugin: 'android'`?

Comment: Yep... in fact, in the last version of Studio when you create a new library it puts "-library" very nice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a good candidate for Product Flavors. The Gradle build system has support for maintaining a single codebase and building multiple apps from that codebase that only differ by a few files changes. See the configuration examples here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants for details.

Comment: Yeah man!! thanks a lot, this is exactly that I had seeking a lot of time, but focusing in external libraries not in gradle. Really many many thanks.